# vi/vim,nmtuiのように画面を変えるにはどうしたら良いですか

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, shell

shellscriptで、vi/vim,nmtuiのように画面を変える（遷移）にはどのようなコマンドを使えば良いのですか？

Answer (score 3):

本家Stack OverflowやUnix & Linux Stack Exchangeに同様の趣旨の質問があるようです。

- [How do programs like man, screen, and vim create temporary overlays? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62180349/)
- [Show output on another "screen" and return to normal when done - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/)

結論から言えば、vim・man・screenのようにいわゆる「代替スクリーン」を構築するフルスクリーンアプリエケーションの実現方法は、使用するターミナル環境に依存するようです。

1つの方法は、terminfoの`smcup`, `rmcup`という機能を利用することです。例えば、上記1つ目の質問に対する[oguz ismailさんの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180844)からコードを借用して、次を実行すると「Hello World!」とだけ書かれた代替スクリーンが3秒間だけ表示されて、また元のコマンドラインに戻ってきます。

```bash
#/bin/bash -
tput smcup  # 代替スクリーンに切替
echo 'Hello world!'
sleep 3
tput rmcup  # 代替スクリーンを終了し、元のスクリーンに戻す
```

私の環境（M2 MacでWarpというターミナルアプリを利用しています）ではこれで代替スクリーンのような挙動を実現できました。

一方、`xterm`や多くのターミナルアプリでは`tput smcup`/`tput rmcup`の代わりにANSIエスケープを利用するとうまくいくことがあるようです。

```bash
#/bin/bash -
printf '\e[7\e[?47h'  # 代替スクリーンに切替
echo 'Hello world!'
sleep 3
printf '\e[2J\e[?47l\e8'  # 代替スクリーンを終了し、元のスクリーンに戻す
```

この方法はWarpでは期待通りの動作になりませんでしたが、macOSの標準ターミナルアプリ（Terminal.app）ではうまくいきました。